SQLFluff - Custom Rule is not loaded
I developed the following custom rule.
My rule definition custom_rules.py is at the same level as .sqlfluff file:
from sqlfluff.core.rules import BaseRule, LintResult
from sqlfluff.core.parser import BaseSegment

class Rule_LL99(BaseRule):
    """Ensure columns with functions are aliased"""

    def _eval(self, segment: BaseSegment, **kwargs):
        print(f"Evaluating segment: {segment}")

        if segment.is_type('function'):
            parent_segment = segment.parent
            if parent_segment and not any(child.is_type('alias_expression') for child in parent_segment.segments):
                return LintResult(anchor=segment, description="Columns where Function has been used must be aliased")
        return None

SQL being tested
SELECT
  id,
  status,
  LOWER("text"),
  CAST("test" AS STRING)
FROM test

Place where I load my rules
[sqlfluff:rules]
custom_rules = custom_rules::Rule_LL99

When running the test
=== [dbt templater] Sorting Nodes...
=== [dbt templater] Compiling dbt project...
=== [dbt templater] Project Compiled.
All Finished  !

I tried to develop a python script to test the rule on its own and I got some issues like wrong name of the rule - something that I would prefer to see during linting, otherwise it's hard to know what's going on.
I'm not a python developer, hence I wonder if there's anything obvious.
My SQLFluff configuration is as follows:
[sqlfluff]
templater = dbt
dialect = bigquery
exclude_rules = RF02, AL01, AL05, ST07, AL03

[sqlfluff:templater:dbt]
project_dir = ./

[sqlfluff:indentation]
tab_space_size = 2
indented_joins = true
indented_using_on = false

[sqlfluff:rules]
custom_rules = custom_rules::Rule_LL99

[sqlfluff:rules:capitalisation.keywords]
capitalisation_policy = upper

[sqlfluff:rules:capitalisation.identifiers]
extended_capitalisation_policy = lower

[sqlfluff:rules:capitalisation.functions]
extended_capitalisation_policy = upper

[sqlfluff:rules:capitalisation.literals]
capitalisation_policy = upper

[sqlfluff:rules:capitalisation.types]
extended_capitalisation_policy = upper

[sqlfluff:rules:aliasing.length]
min_alias_length = 3


I can't find any reference to the custom_rules configuration value which you're using in the SQLFluff docs or codebase. I don't think it exists.
SQLFluff uses pluggy as it's plugin engine, which relies on the python packaging index to discover installed plugins. You don't need to publish your plugin publicly for this to work, you only need to be able to install it locally (i.e. pip install -e /path/to/my/local/plugin). For the necessary structure your plugin has to have there's an example plugin in the SQLFluff GitHub repository.
There's now a guide for this on the SQLFluff docs: https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/latest/guides/setup/developing_custom_rules.html
